# Wordpress - display relationship between blog posts and custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, advanced-custom-fields

I created through ACF a relationship between blog posts and the custom post type, which contains employee profiles. Through the relationship, I am able to display links to the employee's profile, who is the author of a post.

I want to display now the list of posts created by employees at their profiles. I was able to find a [code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213369/display-list-of-posts-containing-a-relationship-field-value-acf) which does that. Unfortunately, whenever I assign more than 5 blog posts to an employee, the next ones are not visible. Would you be able to help me and tweak the code to display more than 5 posts in new rows?

```
<div class="author-content">

        <?php 
        /*
         *  Query posts for a relationship value.
         *  This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string "123" to the database value a:1:{i:0;s:3:"123";} (serialized array)
         */

         $documents = get_posts(array(
                     'post_type' => 'post',
                     'meta_query' => array(
                      array(
                            'key' => 'our_people_author', // name of custom field
                            'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                )
                            )
                        ));

                        ?>
        <?php if( $documents ): ?>

          <ul class="table-author">
             <?php foreach( $documents as $document ): ?>
<li class="singleauth-list">
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $document->ID ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url($document->ID, 'thumbnail');?>" class="people-post-image"></a>
                   <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $document->ID ); ?>" class="author-links">
                     <?php echo get_the_title( $document->ID ); ?>
                   </a>
</li>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
         </ul>
      <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated code to fetch posts, please check is that helpful:

```
$documents = get_posts(array(
                         'post_type' => 'post',
                         'posts_per_page' => -1,
                         'meta_query' => array(
                          array(
                                'key' => 'our_people_author', // name of custom field
                                'value' => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"', // matches exaclty "123", not just 123. This prevents a match for "1234"
                                'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                    )
                                )
                            ));
```